# How to add content to existing remotely located yaml file within Runspace C#

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, asp.net-core, yamldotnet

We can read `yaml` file within `Runspace` using code given in below post

[How to read remote yaml file present in Azure VM from local machine using C# Runspace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62026858/how-to-read-remote-yaml-file-present-in-azure-vm-from-local-machine-using-c-shar/62036555#62036555)

But how to update existing remotely located `yaml` file.

I want to use code using `YamlDotnet` similar to one given in below post to create some new data to be updated into existing `yaml` file.

[Build a Yaml document dynamically from c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37116684/build-a-yaml-document-dynamically-from-c-sharp)

**Update:**

I have inventory yaml file with its contents as below

```
targets:
      - uri: 80.587.459.478
        config:
             transport: ssh
             ssh:
                 user: testlinuxuname
                 private-key: ~/ssh-key/SSH-PrivateKey.txt
                 host-key-check: false
                 run-as: root
      - uri: targetwindows123
        config:
             transport: winrm
             winrm:
                  user: testusername
                  password: testpwd
                  ssl-verify: false
```

Yaml file is located in remote Azure VM.

> **Requirement:**  I want to read `yaml` file which is present in remote azure vm from `C#` and check if particular `uri` value exists
>   or not. If particular `uri` value doesn't exist, then I need to append
>   new `uri` data to `yaml` file. So new record will be appended next to
>   existing data in `yaml` file.
>
> New record will be something like below.
>
> ```
> - uri: targetwindows567
>   config:
>      transport: winrm
>      winrm:
>         user: testusername1
>         password: testpwd1
>         ssl-verify: false
> ```
>
> I want to check if `uri` value `targetwindows567` exists or not in
>   `yaml` file. If it don't exist, then add above records into the remote
>   `yaml` file.

Comment: Can you tell me your specific needs? Because the file read and write operations can be done without such trouble.

Comment: updated question.Kindly check.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways u can try.

1. To open the file over a UNC share (even the default "admin" share, if you have access to it: \servername\driveletter$\restofthepath\file)
2. To copy the file to the local machine, edit it, and then push it back to the remote server, overwriting the old version.

For more details, you can see these [post1](https://serverfault.com/questions/480391/use-powershell-to-edit-a-remote-file-on-a-windows-2008-server) and [post2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432770/how-to-edit-a-file-in-powershell-remoting-session-powershell).

I suggest you download file to local and modify it, then upload to server by powershell or C# code.